# Xcode 6 storyboard does not show UITextView

Tags: ios, ios8, uitextview, uistoryboard, xcode6.1

I am trying to add `UITextView` to the view on storyboard, but just view controller scene displays the text view, not storyboard preview and not real device does not show `UITextView` after build and run.

You can check [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ob2ShsWc59Q) to understand what I am talking about.

I am also trying set uitextview for all devices using relative layout menu, but it does not help.

Comment: My guess is it's there. It is just off-screen. Try to remove all your constraints and check it again. I tried to reproduce the problem, but I experience no problem seeing the text field whatsoever. One way to test if it's off-screen: create an IBOutlet to the text view, in `viewDidLoad` re-center it to let say 160, 200 and see if it is actually offscreen.

Comment: thank you for suggestion, but do you see that on video I create text view next to textfield and without any constrains but by some reasons it does not appear for me not for preview not for devices.

Comment: Yes, in preview it doesn't show. It's the same with me, but it shows in simulator when run.

Comment: @Unheilig have you add any constraint, because for me it works only for constraints?